# Calculating distance traveled in my game

Tags: java, methods

I'm trying to setup a simple energy method that will use 1 energy for every px I traveled in my plain.
Here is my code that won't work. I can't seem to figure out how to get the value of x/y before the movment of my player.

```
public void energy(){
    for(int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++){
        GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);

        if(tempObject.getId() == ID.Player){
            double dis = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(getX() - this.x, 2) + Math.pow(getY() - this.y, 2));
            HUD.ENERGY -= dis;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: An alternative strategy would be to decrease the energy directly in your movement methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a couple of fields in your class called `lastX` and `lastY`. In your `.energy()` method, calculate the distance between current position and `(lastX, lastY)`, and then set `(lastX, lastY)` to the current position.

In this way, you'll keep track of the previous position, and use that to calculate how far it's moved. The rough overview of the method will be:

1. Work out current position.
2. Calculate distance between current position from step 1 and last recorded position.
3. Set last recorded position to the current position retrieved in step 1.

Comment: @Veljko You're welcome :) Please do click the tick to mark as accepted answer if it was useful (gets you some rep points too).

Answer (score 0):

You do realize getX() will return this.x which will become 0 (same for y)? You need to  call it with an instance. 
What you potential want to do it

```
public void energy(Point point1, Point point2){
    for(int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++){
        GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);

        if(tempObject.getId() == ID.Player){
            double dis = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(point1.getX() - point2.getX(), 2) + Math.pow(point1.getY() - point2.getY(), 2));
            HUD.ENERGY -= dis;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I used the solution chiastic-security gave me. Works as I wanted too. Thanks for your answer too.